# how to host django on godaddy

Tags: django, web-hosting

i have made a website using development server and would now like to make the website live. i have purchased godaddy hosting space but dont know how to deploy django project there.

i could only find the following link but could not understand it

http://www.lichun.cc/blog/2012/06/setup-django-1-4-on-godaddy-linux-economy-host/

i am hosting for the first time so any beginner friendly tutorial or reference would be nice

Comment: look here, at least 2.5 years ago it was not really supported.http://support.godaddy.com/groups/go-daddy-customers/forum/topic/django-support/

Comment: it claims that it supports that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Ditch godaddy, purchase hosting with a python-friendly hosting provider.

> https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts

My personal favorite is WebFaction. Cheap, lots of added features, room to grow. Most importantly: *lots* of documentation. http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/getting-started.html

Comment: Your referred  link does not have any info

Comment: BTW, GoDaddy acquired WebFaction and seems like it will be shut down :(